# Moving a quiver in python matplotlib for animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a bouncing ball in python with matplotlib.
I'm trying to add a velocity vector that would point wherever I want, but I want its origin to come from the center of the ball. I did manage to make it so the direction of the quiver changes, but I can't make the origin of the quiver move with the ball.
Is there a way to do that? or do I have to delete the previous quiver and redraw it? and if so, how do I do that?
I know of quiver.set_UVC but can I change the origin also?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide your code - what you've done so far?

Comment: It's currently not possible to change the position of a quiver; see [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11790). However for a single arrow, you do not need quiver, but can use `annotate` or the underlying `FancyArrowPatch`. Or you remove and recreate the quiver in each time step.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try using it with a patch